# what are the advantages of OOP over structural programming?

Tags: java, oop

what is the advanrages oop over structural programming?

Comment: Google "OOP vs structural programming"

Comment: Googling is so hard. [Object Oriented Programming Vs Structured Programming](http://www.coderanch.com/t/99458/patterns/Object-Oriented-Programming-Vs-Structured)

Comment: It is called "structured programming", not "structural programming".  Perhaps you are confusing it with "procedural programming".

Comment: (FWIW - structured programming is essentially programming without GOTO. It is (was) a reaction to spaghetti programming that was prevalent in the the 1960's.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main advantage that it allows you to control the complexity. You can create an object which represenets some real one, put the logic inside it and hide all the implementation details behind some interface, which is public.

That way, the client has no idea how the object is implemented but deals with public interface to control it. For understanding suggest the program interface of the car:

```
public interface Car {

   void speedUp(int mvh);

   void breakDown(int mvh);

}
```

Then, you can have a lot of implementations - Ferrari or WV, or something else. They all will have some implementation details, but all have the common interface, and don't need cleint to be aware of implementation details.

Answer (score 3):

Object Oriented Programming has many benefits over structured programming. some of them are reusability,reliability and maintainability.OOP akso helps to reduce large to smaller more manageable problems.In terms of extensibility and reusability,for instance:"Encapsulation allows the internal implementations of a class to be modified without requiring changes to its services (i.e methods).It is also allows new classes to be added to a system,without major modifications to the system.Inheritance allows the class hierarchy to be further refined, and combined with polymorphism, the superclass doed not have know about the new class, i.e, modifications do not have to be made at the superclass"

Answer (score 1):

If you understand what Object orientated programming is about the answer is self evident. OO programming is a superset of procedural code can do, so by definition it is richer in helping you solve any problem.

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to define and assign responsibility for a given set of data to a given set of code, and it allows you to group responsibilities into a unified interface.